# Rails: How to create a user that has a `belongs_to` association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am brand new to the world of rails so please forgive my ignorance with this question :)

I am currently setting up a new app that has two models:

1. Account
2. User

My seed file looks like this:

```rb
account = Account.create!(name: 'Account Name')

account.users.create!(
  first_name: 'Test',
  last_name: 'Test',
  email: 'test@test.com,
  password: 'test',
  owner: true
)
```

And the users model is:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
 ...
end
```

I have created a custom Devise registrations controller to let new users sign up:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # GET /sign_up
  def new
    render inertia: 'Auth/Register', props: {}
  end

  # POST
  def create # rubocop:disable Lint/UselessMethodDefinition
    super
  end

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit( :email, :password, :first_name, :last_name)
  end
end
```

BUT! I need to pre-create an account for a user before I actually create the user here and this is something I have been stuck on for a few days with no luck (to the point I've considered changing the association's).

The error is:

```
Account must exist
```

Which makes sense because we don't have an account when we create a new user which is what i need to do before the user is registered.

My best guess was I needed to do something like:

```rb
# POST
  def create
    account = Account.create!(name: 'Test')
    account.users.create!(sign_up_params)
  end
```

to mimic the logic of the seeds file but this seems distinctly wrong to me and doesn't work.

So my question is, is it possible and how can I pre-create an Account model for a user and then associate it to the user in the registrations create method before the user is persisted to the database?

In my final production code, the goal would be to create an Account `type` that will be created and associated with a user on registration but for now just getting a very basic MVC up and running is the goal :)

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: your current approach should work. Are you missing the Account `has_many :users` association? That's required to do `account.users`

Comment: I don't think so! My account modal looks like:

```ruby
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :organizations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Could it be the way Devise is trying to handle the creation?

Comment: There's a `has_many :users` there, so that isn't the issue. _"This seems distinctly wrong to me"_ it's not ... you just need to figure out why it's not working. You haven't shared a lot of info about what the exact problem is.

Comment: Hi Max! Thanks so much for getting back to me! After more digging around I have found what I think to be the root of the issue, and that's how I am handling the user redirect on the register. I can confirm the approach I am using actually does work in terms of something getting into the database but the user is thrown into a default Devise route that thinks nothing has happened, hence the error. So I think what I need to do is manually handed the routing now with something like: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

Comment: "This seems distinctly wrong to me", please forgive my ignorance on this one, I am new to rails. What I had meant was: "it would be nice to use the default Devise register method without needing to edit it" but since I am indeed doing something custom that should be an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think the account is supposed to belong to the user, not the opposite.

The user model **User.rb** should look like this:

```
has_one :account
```

And the account model **Account.rb** should look like this:

```
belongs_to :user
```

And to create an account once the user is created, you can simply add this line to your user model:

```
after_create :create_account
```

and the account will be created automatically.

Comment: That would work if I re-ordered my models but in my application, I specifically wanted an Account to the SSoT that could contain multiple users since we might have an account that needs more than one user at a time!

Answer (score 0):

What about using?

```
user = User.new(sign_up_params)
user.build_account(name: 'Test')
user.save!
```

Comment: No dice! It looks to me like the methods do work BUT for some reason the default Devise layout seems to think it doesn't work since the record is created in the database but then I am redirected to an unstyled Devise sign up page with the errors displayed, so perhaps I need to not call `super` in the register method and manually handle it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line `belongs_to :account` in User model.
I would suggest you break your User model in two models

1. User
2. UserDetails

You can then add `belongs_to :account` in UserDetails model.
This will help in independent creation of users, will not be affected by account.
Something like below.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user_detail
  ...
end

class UserDetails < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :account
  ...
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_details
  ...
end
```